# How to view the contents of my DVD in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation, iso, dvd

I am using Ubuntu but I want to reinstall it that's why I burnt ubuntu iso file in a DVD.I am going through the exact same process as given in

> https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu

But whenever I want to see the contents of the DVD, I see nothing when I  click the DVD-R disk option in the file manager.

Also when I am trying to boot from the DVD to install OS, it doesn't work and starts normally.

> So is there any way I can see the content of the DVD through terminal or through any other method?
>
> Or I am not doing the process correctly and the image hasn't been burnt yet?Here is my screenshot of the DVD after writing on the disk.

[image: Blank dvd]

**P.S. First time I burnt it got stucked checking the image checksum so I closed it after seeing several answers here on that problem.I again burned the image but again it doesn't show any content.So any help will be helpful.Thank you..:)**

Comment: Yes, the DVD got ejected.That means it's done?Actually, that happened when I burnt it the second time.But I don't know how to check that?

Comment: Auto-ejecting the disk means that whatever you told it to burn is complete. Can you boot from the DVD?

Comment: Yes, I know that after burn the disk auto ejects and it happened in my case also.But I cannot boot from the DVD when I go to the BIOS and do the settings.It boots normally.That's why i am asking that are the contents not visible after burning them to DVD?

Comment: ' Blank DVD-R Disc' says that the disk is empty ('blank'). So the burning did not succeed (not finish?). In case of burning errors, the disk might be ejected as well, depending on your software and configuration.

Comment: Is there any way to check if the contents have been burnt or not?

Comment: Sure, re-insert the burnt disk and look at it in the file manager. It it still says 'blank' and offers to burn, then nothing was burnt. May be a hardware issue.

Comment: Yes,I burnt the disk again and it got self-ejected as required.But even after that I see nothing in the contents.